# footer page end distance

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, footer

I added a footer to my page. When it is a page length it covers the content.
There should be a distance between the end of the page and the footer.
It's ok when the page is 100 percent, but it happens when the page gets longer
[image]

But I want a distance between.This is scss.

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #222831;
  min-height: 5vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

This is my layout

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./footer";
import Header from "./header";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Header />
      <div className="children">{children}</div>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

This is my footer

```
import {
  AiFillLinkedin,
  AiFillGithub,
  AiFillInstagram,
  AiOutlineMail,
} from "react-icons/ai";
export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className="footer">
      <div className="logo">
        <span className="bracket">{"<"}</span>
        <p>Handcrafted by</p>
        <span className="bracket">{"{"}</span>
        <span className="name">{"ömer"}</span>
        <span className="bracket">{"}"}</span>
        <span className="bracket">{"/>"}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="icons">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/omersahin1/">
          <AiFillLinkedin className="icon" size={20} />
        </a>
        <a href="https://github.com/1sahinomer1">
          <AiFillGithub className="icon" size={20} />
        </a>
        <a href="https://github.com/shnomr">
          <AiFillInstagram className="icon" size={20} />
        </a>
        <a href="mailto:1sahinomer1@gmail.com">
          <AiOutlineMail className="icon" size={20} />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `position: fixed`.

Comment: What should I use? How can I fix it there always?

Comment: I usually make sure the body has a min-height of 100vh. There are lots of ways to do it; check out this link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/